# Encode Swift object in Objective-c project

Tags: objective-c, swift, nscoding

I have a swift class integrated in my objective-c project and it returns me an object that I can access and use. I've tried (in an obj-c file) to create a property with this object and encode/decode it using standard methods

```
- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder
```

and

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder
```

But my application crashes for "unrecognized selector sent to instance XXX".

I guess I can't serialize swift objects in this direct way, and I don't know how to solve right now. Thank you for your help

Comment: Please you can write your class (more code) to be detected the error?

Comment: I don't know what code to post, I try to serialize the swift object as usual..     [encoder encodeObject:self.OBAds forKey:@"OBAds"];

Comment: It seems to me that the OBAds object doesn't implement NSCoder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a simple class swift. You may take this as an example. I hope we can be of your help.

```
    class UserBean:NSObject,NSCoding {

    var idUser:NSNumber?
    var username:String?
    var password:String?
    var email:String?
    var token:String?
    var fonte:String?
    var idFacebook:String?
    var uuid:String?
    var profilo = UserProfileBean()

    override init() {
        super.init()
        self.profilo = UserProfileBean()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        idUser      = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("idUser") as? NSNumber
        username    = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("username") as? String
        password    = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("password") as? String
        email       = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("email") as? String
        token       = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("token") as? String
        fonte       = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("fonte") as? String
        idFacebook  = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("idFacebook") as? String
        uuid        = (aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("uuid") as? String)!
        profilo     = (aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("profilo") as? UserProfileBean)!

    }
    func encodeWithCoder(aCoder: NSCoder) {
        aCoder.encodeObject(idUser,     forKey: "idUser")
        aCoder.encodeObject(username,   forKey: "username")
        aCoder.encodeObject(password,   forKey: "password")
        aCoder.encodeObject(email,      forKey: "email")
        aCoder.encodeObject(token,      forKey: "token")
        aCoder.encodeObject(fonte,      forKey: "fonte")
        aCoder.encodeObject(idFacebook ,forKey: "idFacebook")
        aCoder.encodeObject(uuid ,forKey: "idFacebook")
        aCoder.encodeObject(profilo,forKey: "profilo")

    }  
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

In order for this to work you will have to:

a) write the set of encodeWithCoder methods in your Swift class

-or-

b) inherit from an Obj-C class that does

(b) caused me confusion until the simple truth became clear: Swift objects do *not* descend from NSObject, so a lot of the machinery you expect simply isn't there, and that includes the entire `coder` system. Quite a bit of functionality becomes available when you change:

```
class myClass {
```

to

```
class myClass: NSObject {
```